# qTranslate dates and times

Tags: qtranslate

I've just installed qTranslate and it works like a doll. Only problem is that date bug that's been around for a while. Everywhere I've found via Google says it is due to the two percent signs in qtrans_ulils.php, for $strftime_parameters[]. However, if I correct this to only one percent, I don't get the problem anymore, but I do get a huge hunk of an error...CRT, it claims, in the qtrans_core.php.

```
Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected in C:\var\htdocs\maud\wp-content\plugins\qtranslate\qtranslate_core.php on line 455 Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected in C:\var\htdocs\maud\wp-content\plugins\qtranslate\qtranslate_core.php on line 455 Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected in C:\var\htdocs\maud\wp-content\plugins\qtranslate\qtranslate_core.php on line 455 Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected in C:\var\htdocs\maud\wp-content\plugins\qtranslate\qtranslate_core.php on line 455 Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected in C:\var\htdocs\maud\wp-content\plugins\qtranslate\qtranslate_core.php on line 455 at 09:06 PM
```

I can't really comprehend why it's doing this...help.

Red

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://was955.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/php-warning-invalid-crt-parameters-detected-by-qtranslate-on-wordpress/

Here's a quote from the site:

> If you use **qTranslate** plugin with WordPress, you may see many warning
>   message like below information on Apache and PHP with Windows OS.
>
> **qTranslate Warning: Invalid CRT parameters detected in … \wp-content\plugins\qtranslate\qtranslate_core.php on line 447**
>
> I will give you 1 method to resolve this problem if you want to remove
>   many warning messages
>
> How to remove warning messages
>
> If you want to remove many warning messages, you should edit ‘**…\wp-content\plugins\qtranslate\qtranslate_core.php**‘ (around line **455**) like below codes:

```
$search[] = '/(([^%])%4|^%4)/'; $replace[] = '${2}'.$date; // date U $format = preg_replace($search,$replace,$format);

// Add Windows
if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
  $format = str_replace('%P','%p',$format);
}

return $before.strftime($format, $date).$after;
```

> It is very easy problem. You cannot use ‘**%P**’ that format in strftime
>   function ( PHP ) with Windows OS. You should use ‘**%p**’ if you want to
>   remove warning messages with Windows OS.
>
> %p UPPER-CASE 'AM' or 'PM' based on the given time
>   Example: AM for 00:31, PM for 22:23
>
> %P lower-case 'am' or 'pm' based on the given time
>   Example: am for 00:31, pm for 22:23